# Thickness of thin-film interference

Tags: homework-and-exercises, optics, interference

A thin film of alcohol ($n = 1.36$) lies on a flat glass plate ($n = 1.51$). When monochromatic
light, whose wavelength can be changed, is incident normally, the intensity of the reflected
light is a minimum for $λ = 512 nm$ and a maximum for $λ = 640 nm$. What is the thickness of
the film?

**Working -** 
I know that a maximum occurs at $2nt=(m+1/2)λ$, where $n$ is the refractive index of the thin film (in this case, the alcohol), $t$ is the thickness of the thin film and $λ=640 nm$.

I also know that a minimum occurs at $2nt=mλ$, this time $λ=512nm$.

I tried plugging in the relevant numbers but realized that I didn't have an $m$ value for either equation. Do I need to find the $m$ value for both equations or is there another way to find the thickness without finding the respective $m$ values. Any support is greatly appreciated. Feel free to edit my question for clarity. Thank you

Comment: Hi Joe and welcome to the Physics SE! Please note that this is not a homework help site. Please see [this Meta post on asking homework questions](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/714/how-do-i-ask-homework-questions-on-physics-stack-exchange) and [this Meta post for "check my work" problems](http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/questions/6093/should-any-check-my-work-questions-be-made-on-topic).

Comment: Thanks for the friendly introduction John Rennie. I've read the documents you sent me but I am still a bit unsure how I can edit my question so that it suits the site better. Any suggestions cause I am stuck with this question and need assistance.